# validate presence of hash element & times when hash is not set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm validating on one stage

```
params[:user][:address]
```

But there are times when `params[:user]` are not set. What should I use to check against this? `blank?`, `nil?`, or `present?`? The objective is to make this check on as few lines as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unless params[:user] && params[:user][:address].present?
  # do something
end
```

Comment: I thought that unless is just  "if not" ?

Comment: Yes, `unless` is nothing more than `if not`. I think it reads better in this case, but you can make your own judgement. Because of operator precedence, you may need extra parentheses if you use `if not`.

Answer (score 0):

with arrays

```
unless @banners.try(:[], 2)
```

with objects should try )